# Smart Target Icon doesn't appear in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, smarttarget

I have a problem i one of my environments. When I am logged in XPM, I can't see the target icon neither targeted regions in my properties page. But ST works because i can see the promotion selected.

In other environments I can edit promotions from XPM.

[image]
[image]

here is my HTML code:

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Test st</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <noscript>
                    <div class="nojs">Javascript must be enabled for the correct page display</div>
                </noscript>

                <!-- Start Promotion Region: {"RegionID": "Carousel" } -->




                <span>
                    <!-- Start Query: {
    "RegionID" : "Carousel",
    "MaxItems" : 1,
    "Experiments" : [
    ],
    "Promotions" : [
        {
            "PromotionID": "752abc11-884a-40b5-80b3-ab5ec4ddba80",
            "PromotionTitle": "Test Carousel",
            "IncludedInPage": true,
            "Items" : [
                { "ComponentID": "tcm:164-81776-16", "ComponentTemplateID": "tcm:164-81775-32", "IncludedInPage": true }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
-->




                    <span>
                        <!-- Start Promotion: { "PromotionID": "752abc11-884a-40b5-80b3-ab5ec4ddba80", "RegionID" : "Carousel"} -->

                        <span>
                            <!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:164-81776", "ComponentModified" : "2015-06-25T09:19:55", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:164-81775-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2015-07-23T14:05:59", "IsRepositoryPublished" : true } -->
                            <span>
                                <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:sys_literal/custom:value[1]"} -->ST works</span>
                        </span>


                        <!-- End Promotion -->
                    </span>





                    <!-- End Query: -->
                </span>




                <!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:164-82353-64","PageModified":"2015-06-24T17:44:33","PageTemplateID":"tcm:164-82356-128","PageTemplateModified":"2015-07-27T13:38:44"} -->
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="http://SES000900-1667/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"/>
            </body>
        </html>
```

When I put this sentence in chrome console with editor.aspx frame,
**Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SmartTarget.Model.ListTargetedRegions.listTargetedRegions.getXml()**
 appears this error 
[image]

Can anyone helps me please?

Thanks!

Comment: What versions are you using (CM and Browser).
And are you using the same version(s) in 'the other environments'?

Comment: First step is to check if the XPM markup is present and valid. If possible, please post the HTML source from the browser (replacing any sensitive data with dummy text).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers! I use Tridion 2013 SP1 and Firefox 38.0.5, and I use the same version i the resto of environmets.

Comment: I recognize this. I've already given all of my input through Customer Support already, so I doubt I'll be able to come up with more without additional information.

Comment: I have searched some conexion error between Preview_webservice and Fredhopper with Fiddler, but I can´t see anything, preview_webservice's log is clear and SmartTarget_webservice too.

Comment: The HTML doesn't seem to be completely valid. Could you try using https://validator.w3.org/check to fix the validation errors and see if that fixes the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I have resolved my issue,
the problem was a configuration in the Publication Targets.
I created 2 similar Publication Targets (`Previsualization` and `PrevisST`), both had the same `webservice_preview` url,and both use the same `URLs` to access but only `PrevisST` had filled `Targeting layer`.

When I tried to modify my page from XPM, the default target selected was `Previsualization` whose Targeting settings weren't configured.

I have solved the issue by removing `targeting layer settings` from `PrevisST` and filling in `Previsualization`.

I hope to help someone with the same problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is there any information being shown in the logs of Odata, and are the configurations in line for the Odata service.

- cd_ambient_conf.xml has the SmartTarget cartridge ?
- smarttarget_conf.xml has the regions and is connecting to the right server ?

Comment: that is my preview_webservice's cd_ambient_conf.xml

    <Cartridges>
        <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
        <Cartridge File="smarttarget_odata_cartridge_conf.xml" />
    </Cartridges>

Preview_webservice's smarttarget_conf has the regions and conecting to the right server.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an ADF or SmartTarget, but rather something with the client-side markup for the regions.

Comment: I use the same templates in both environments, I think there will be a conection with Fredhooper, but i can´t find the error...
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jose, Have you got the solution of this problem. I am facing the same issue in Development environment. First one, some times smart target regions are not showing in page properties in XPM and also component fields are not showing editable. When I refresh the page 1-2 times it start working correctly.Second one, broken line showing in your screenshot in XPM. If you already got the solution please share..

Comment: I'm still getting this error, I'm searching in .net fusion log for error in some dll. I hope to resolve this problem as soon as possible.